# Организация расписания с плавающими неделями (числитель/знаменатель)

Tags: php, mysql

Перед мной стоит задача реализовать расписание в школе, где стоит есть уроки, в первой недели числитель на второй, в тот же день, знаменатель.
Соотвественно, уроки меняются. Как реализовать на PHP?
Как лучше реализовать базу.

Спасибо.

Comment: Добавляете 2 записи на один день и одно время. При выборке по каждому дню и времени смотрите сколько записей. Если больше 1, то плавающая неделя. Можно по дополнительному признаку и текущей недели можно выводить только одну запись из двух

Comment: Составляйте 2 отдельных расписания и группируйте при выводе или расчёте суммарных показателей.